Can the US president legally kill at will?
Following the ruling by SCOTUS in Trump v. United States (2024) that Presidents enjoy absolute immunity for their exclusive powers and presumptive immunity for their remaining official acts, I have seen it claimed by many that the president could kill people, e.g. assassinate a political rival using the forces at his disposal, and be immune to subsequent prosecution.
For example, this question was asked by Judge Sotomayor during the hearing of above case.
To me, the answer is quite obviously a resounding "no". Yes, the US president is the commander-in-chief, but his official duties are to lead the militia in its defense of the country. So, in order for an assassination to be considered an official act, it would need to be demonstrated that the act was done in reasonable adherence to said duty, which clearly would not be possible to demonstrate (in practice it would probably be the prosecution who would have to demonstrate the inverse, but that would be trivial.).
So why is Judge Sotomayor, and others, implying that this precedent allows the US president to kill people at will?

Obama started killing Americans with Predator drones more than 15 years ago, and nobody has dared to prosecute him. So it is already stablished that POTUS can kill Americans at will. The American Civil Liberties Union sued the government because of the targeted killings of three American citizens, some of them who hadn't even been accused of committing any crimes. The Obama administration claimed its right to kill whoever they wanted to, without restrictions or supervision.
The most the ACLU got from the courts was the government producing a document detailing the alibis that could be used to justify killing an American citizen at will. At present, it would be enough to label the target as "terrorist", and then you're safe to go and kill the target - there are no prerequisites to being considered a terrorist.

The problem with those kinds of U.S. war crimes, crimes against humanity and otherwise morally dubious actions is that there often was a lack of intent to prosecute. Like Obama did it, but the Republican party didn't dissent, on the contrary they approved of the drone program and extended it under Trump while limiting it's transparency. Also, being pretty cynic, these problems were far away. Like this being labeled terrorist and killed without due process was for citizens abroad. While their own descend into tyranny should still bother the U.S. a lot more.

This answer is somewhat incomplete. It doesn't mention Executive Order 11905 or Reid v. Covert, which arguably put these sort of extrajudicial assassinations on very shaky ground, legally. Nor does it mention that the case Al-Aulaqi v. Obama —the ACLU lawsuit mentioned in the question—was not resolved in favor of the Obama administration, but rather dismissed for lack of standing to file the case and on the basis that decisions of military foreign policy were non-judiciable.

This is relevant because the main concern of the dismissal for being non-judiciable was that a decision requiring future oversight of details of foreign military operations fell outside the remit of the court. While not a particularly beneficial decision, it is doubtful that it created a precedent that removed liability for individuals for any actions engaged in under any such circumstances, and since it mentioned that this question was tied to the facts of a particular case, it's also doubtful that it applied unrestrictedly to domestic official actions by the executive.

The relevance of the Trump case is that it (a) applies to all official acts, not just foreign military policy, (b) is an actual ruling on the merits of a case, not a dismissal for lack of standing or judiciability of a specific case, and (c) establishes a lack of individual liability, instead of merely barring preemptive oversight. These are substantive legal questions, so the answer is incomplete, insofar as the impression one could get from it is that the Trump case is of no legal relevance.

As for its practical relevance, that remains to be seen, but it would seem much easier to justify, for instance, blanket lifetime immunity for "accidentally" killing an activist during a presidentially ordered domestic FBI raid under this ruling than to argue that such an action was actually a foreign military action against a terrorist (the non-judiciability of legitimate foreign policy decisions has not previously prevented criminal liability in any case).

@Obie2.0: I certainly do interpret the SCOTUS ruling as a statement about judiciability.  It does not make POTUS immune to remedies which exist outside court, such as impeachment and the ballot box.

@BenVoigt - It's not that the recent ruling is not a statement about judiciability, and it certainly does not prevent impeachment or compel reelection. It's that the case was not dismissed, and I don't think Al-Aulaqi v. Obama really precluded individual liability. What the ruling deemed as not judiciable was details of military and foreign policy, but indicated in my comment, people have still been held criminally liable despite acting in the service of military foreign policy. But the Trump case seems to close that possibility for the president, even after they have left office.

Anwar Al-Aulaqi was a Jihadist and member of al-Qaeda.
He was a member of one of the most notorious terrorist organizations on earth and played a role in orchestrating the groups actions in Yemen for which he was issued a death warrant by the Yemeni government.
They didn't exactly kill an innocent person, but I am surprised they didn't revoke his citizenship.

Can someone clarify something for me; when were Predator drones used against Americans??

@ConnieMnemonic Anwar al-Awlaki was an American citizen who was killed with a drone strike. He was in Yemen at the time, and accused of being with al-Qaeda. You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anwar_al-Awlaki

@ChellCPlus it is generally only possible to deprive a US citizen of that citizenship involuntarily if it was obtained by fraud.

This Obama-era license to kill only applies outside of US soil, doesn't it?

@gerrit Not really. The Obama administration produced a document saying that the Government considered itself authorized to kill american citizens without supervision if a series of circumstances concurred. This circumstances were, among others, the citizen being designated a danger to the security of the state, and having them captured by security forces deemed too complicated or risky. While at the moment this meant "terrorists on foreign soil" it can equally be "bothering rival POTUS candidate, who has too many supporters to risk a police detention in the open".

It's important to note what the ruling actually covers. I'll borrow from this good summary on Law.SE


For acts within the President's "exclusive sphere" of constitutional authority (also referred to as "conclusive and preclusive" authority), President has absolute immunity from criminal prosecution (pp. 6-9).
For "official" acts that are not within that central core, (“acts pursuant to an express or implied authorization of Congress,” or in a “zone of twilight” where "he and Congress may have concurrent authority"), the President does not have absolute immunity. Instead, here the President only has presumptive immunity from criminal prosecution (pp. 9-15). For such acts, the President is immune from criminal proseuction "unless the Government can show that applying a criminal prohibition to that act would pose no 'dangers of intrusion on the authority and functions of the Executive Branch'" (p. 14).
For unofficial acts, "there is no immunity" (p. 15).


Rekesoft is right in pointing to Obama as a case where the President unilaterally killed a US citizen without any due process. That having been said, the person in question was Anwar al-Awlaki. In this case, the man might have been a US Citizen, but he was living in a foreign country and actively fomenting terrorist sentiments. That doesn't apply to a lot of people. It's arguable that killing someone who is encouraging violence against Americans on foreign soil is an official act.
Let's take a look at a more pragmatic case. A quote by Trump himself

"I could stand in the middle of Fifth Avenue and shoot somebody, and I wouldn't lose any voters, OK?" Trump remarked at a campaign stop at Dordt College in Sioux Center, Iowa. "It's, like, incredible."

Assume, for the sake of argument, that Trump actually did this while still President. As we've seen in the campaign finance case, Trump would be subjected to state laws about guns as well as attempted or actual murder. It would also be hard to argue this was an official act as President.
Let's pivot to Sotomayor's example. This is the full text of the ruling. (page 29)

The President of the United States is the most powerful person in the country, and possibly the world. When he uses his official powers in any way, under
the majority’s reasoning, he now will be insulated from criminal prosecution. Orders the Navy’s Seal Team 6 to assassinate a political rival? Immune. Organizes a military coup to hold onto power? Immune. Takes a bribe in ex-
change for a pardon? Immune. Immune, immune, immune.

The problem for Sotomayor is that Trump is still under Federal indictment for acts taken while President. The ruling only specifies that Presidential immunity actually exists, not how much is covered by it. How much of the three Federal indictments remain is something to be sorted out by courts (and SCOTUS left considerable wiggle room). If Trump were as immune as she claimed, the indictments would have been thrown out. Thus a President can still face charges after leaving office (something long established by Gerald Ford pardoning Richard Nixon).
Both the Seal Team 6 assassination and coup examples fall outside the Article II "core" powers. Moreover, the people who would have to carry out such orders would not share in any immunity claims. Being given an order by a President does not automatically make said order lawful. In the My Lai massacre, military personnel were charged with crimes (only the commander was found guilty). Both hypothetical orders could be considered illegal (Law.SE has a good discussion on the legal ramifications)
But the greatest torpedo to Sotomayor's dissent was in the ruling itself (starting page 39, some notes trimmed for brevity)

Coming up short on reasoning, the dissents repeatedly level variations of the accusation that the Court has rendered the President “above the law.” As before, that “rhetorically chilling” contention is “wholly unjustified.” Like everyone else, the President is subject to prosecution in his unofficial capacity. But unlike anyone else, the President is a branch of government, and the Constitution vests in him sweeping powers
and duties. Accounting for that reality—and ensuring that
the President may exercise those powers forcefully, as the
Framers anticipated he would—does not place him above
the law; it preserves the basic structure of the Constitution
from which that law derives.
The dissents’ positions in the end boil down to ignoring the Constitution’s separation of powers and the Court’s precedent and instead fear mongering on the basis of extreme hypotheticals about a future where the President “feels empowered to violate federal criminal law.” The dissents overlook the more likely prospect of an Executive Branch that cannibalizes itself, with each successive President free to prosecute his predecessors, yet unable to boldly
and fearlessly carry out his duties for fear that he may be next.

Assuming that either Sotomayor scenario ever happens, it's unlikely a Federal court would read this decision and assume that a political execution via Presidential power is subject to Presidential immunity (especially if Congress were to impeach and remove said President).

Even though the hush money payments took place before Trump was President, there's now a decent chance this conviction will be overturned because some of the evidence came from official acts (such as his tweets, which he used as an official communication method)  that took place while he was President, and the ruling says that these can't be used as evidence.

"Moreover, the people who would have to carry out such orders would not share in any immunity claims." - the President can pardon federal crimes. Trump has pardoned actual killers (four Blackwater military contractors convicted, one of first-degree murder, for their involvement in the Nisour Square massacre).

I rather disagree with this reasoning. Roberts put almost any kind of talk by the president to the underlings (e.g. those in the DOJ) as an official act. So, POTUS telling Seal Team 6 to do this or that is very similar.

-1. The judicial branch not adhering to it's own decision does not "torpedo Sotomayor's dissent", that's paradoxical. As ruled this week, the president has absolute immunity for official acts and assumed immunity for the "outer limit" of his duties. It's a big stretch to declare deploying Seal Team 6 as commander in chief, not an official act, while deploying the justice department in any way you see fit, is.

Worse, a president firing a subordinate for not breaking the law would be immune. He can fire the AG until one agrees to assassinate his rival. And we can't even consider his motivations.

"it's unlikely a Federal court would" Why is it unlikely? Considering the president appoints those judges and with enough "gratuity" anything is possible.

The court not immediately throwing out all of the indictments only says at most two things: (1) they haven't gone completely insane and know the standard and wholly unremarkable, implication-free procedure here is to remand with new instructions, even if they are already convinced their instructions lead only to one conclusion; (2) they're just helping Trump stall for time, as now it will take months for the courts to come to a decision on this, then many more months for appellate courts, before eventually SCOTUS tells them the correct answer.

Exactly how can you argue that giving an order to the US armed forces not a "core power" of the president?  Remember, the illegality of the communicated information doesn't change things under the majority opinion.

"Moreover, the people who would have to carry out such orders would not share in any immunity claims." True, but the President can also promise to pardon them if it's a federal crime, and if pardoned they would have immunity.

This, imho, is a much more detailed and reasonable answer than the top-voted one. The top-voted one just affirms to what the question asks without providing much details.

"something long established by Gerald Ford pardoning Richard Nixon": that established nothing. The president doesn't have to confirm that charges are possible before pardoning someone.

Something is off about the last quote here. Presidents have not had this level of immunity before and there's relatively few criminal charges against former presidents. So why suggest that former presidents would be bombarded by criminal charges? It's not happened so far. The fears about immunity causing more presidential crimes do not have an equivalent track record to prove or disprove the idea. But not having immunity clearly does not pose the threat that they suggest. Or it would be easy to see all of the existing criminal charges on former presidents who didn't have this level of immunity

-1. Far from torpedoing the dissenting opinion, the final quote affirms it. A major part of the separation of powers is the concept of checks and balances, and this decision sets precedent that the President would be immune to the majority of checks and balances the other two branches of government have. Now any reprehensible action the President takes that is even slightly related to their official duties is prohibitively difficult if not impossible to hold accountable, and ordering a drone strike or an FBI hit on a political rival is well within the scope of an "official act".

The majority by this ruling actually makes possible (and more likely) the very concern which by this ruling they hope to avoid -- that Presidents in office may unethically target former Presidents -- and adds to it the possibility of targeting future rivals as well. The Court is in effect saying, Presidents may not prosecute their predecessors, but they may bring harm or threat of harm to any rival outside of the judicial process, legally or illegally, so long as they can make an official case for doing so -- in which case even any evidence to the contrary is inadmissible.

One of the specific core powers enumerated in the ruling is commanding the military.  Regarding the Seal Team 6 objection, that is 100% the President commanding the military, so they would be absolutely immune from civil or criminal penalties.  They could still be impeached if in office, but face no consequences beyond that.

@JasonPatterson And that order would be 100% illegal. Moreover, if that were really the net result of the ruling, Joe Biden could have had executed Donald Trump by now. Remember, the ruling leaves open for a President to merely argue that some action was a core power. It does not automatically make everything legal.

@Machavity Yes, it would be an illegal order, but that's the point.  You don't need immunity for legal actions.  And yes, Biden could have executed Trump, that's the other point.

Laws are just a piece of paper
You're looking at this from a purely legalistic perspective, which makes sense in some contexts and doesn't in others. What the law says or doesn't say about the President killing an election rival hardly matters. What matters is the reaction of society at large to such an event, particularly the reaction of the armed forces and other members of the community who have firearms and the will to use them.
In the US its very likely that such an assassination will be seen as extremely controversial and society will find a way to remove such a President from power. The President could stand around and yell words about how the law says X and how they must be granted immunity but any law is just a piece of paper and will not protect them in an extreme tail case scenario where the action is an obvious violation of societal standards. Or perhaps the President will convince the army to join his side and effectively takeover power as a new dictator - this is something that frequently happens in various unstable developing nations.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Yes, the US
president is the commander-in-chief, but his official duties are to
lead the militia in its defense of the country. So, in order for an
assassination to be considered an official act, it would need to be
demonstrated that the act was done in reasonable adherence to said
duty

I hope that if such a scenario were ever to arise, then the courts would indeed chart a course along those lines.  That seems to be in the interest of justice, and consistent with both the SC decision and the founding principles of the country.

So why is Judge Sotomayor, and others, implying that this precedent
allows the US president to kill people at will?

I'm inclined to think that Justice Sotomayor had a variety of reasons, some of them tending to the rhetorical.  Nevertheless, neither Sotomayor nor any of the rest of us can be sure that a court faced with such a scenario would indeed rule as you suppose.  One might, for example, halt the analysis at the President being empowered to issue orders to the U.S. armed forces, and on that basis decide that immunity for official actions applied.  Whatever else her motivations may be, Sotomayor would prefer not to open a door for future courts to do the wrong thing (as you or I would judge it) in such a case.
Although I take Sotomayor's assassination scenario as somewhat hyperbolic, and I don't care much for the style and tone of her dissent, she does have some some important things to say.  I rarely agree with her on controversial questions, but here, she persuaded me (through other, more analytical parts of her dissent) that the majority decision in this case has a shaky foundation at best, and contains components that seem both unwarranted and at odds with precedent.

You're asking two diff Qs here. You may or may not agree with the 3 liberal judges, but if you want to read their reasoning, I'm sure that's easy to find. Your title Q seems to be asking if they're right in their assessment, which may be veering towards the opinion-based. IIRC the SCOTUS majority judgement was that another judge has to determine whether anything the president does is in an official capacity or not.
Killing people with their own bare hands in a fit of rage, might not qualify as an official act. Ordering someone to be killed by the military may well qualify though [as official action], even if against Posse Comitatus, etc., e.g. on US soil.
So the question, seems to me, is whether this broad presidential immunity for any official acts essentially leaves only impeachment as a recourse. And who'd be there to impeach him if he orders the military to arrest the opposition or the entire Congress? (And the military follows through. The only issue before a judge then would be whether such an order was official, not whether it was legal in any other sense, unless the act was first deemed unofficial. And it's hard to argue in any sensible way that POTUS ordering the military to do something is not an official act.)
FWTW, from press snippets:

Jackson warned that under the majority's "new Presidential accountability mode," a hypothetical president "who admits to having ordered the assassinations of his political rivals or critics...or one who indisputably instigates an unsuccessful coup...has a fair shot at getting immunity."
The chief justice dismissed the dissents, suggesting that his three liberal colleagues had misinterpreted the majority's opinion and were engaging in "fear mongering." Roberts argued that they "strike a tone of chilling doom that is wholly disproportionate to what the Court actually does today." He wrote that "like everyone else, the President is subject to prosecution in his unofficial capacity."

Furthermore, Chief justice Roberts put under the clout of official acts almost any kind of talk of POTUS with/to his underlings.

But Chief Justice John Roberts, writing for the majority, preemptively determined that Trump’s interactions with justice department officials were official acts because they are part of the executive branch and answer to the president.
Roberts also determined that Trump’s interactions with Pence were presumptively immune, since the president discussing responsibilities with the vice-president was an instance of official conduct. The burden was on prosecutors to prove otherwise, Roberts wrote.

So, POTUS telling Seal Team 6 to do this or that is very likely similarly construed as an official act, at least "presumptively".
Ibid (WaPo):

Sotomayor warned that a president is now immune from criminal prosecution if he orders the Navy’s SEAL Team 6 to assassinate a political rival, or if he organizes a coup to hold on to political power.


If it helps improve the answer, wasn't firing the AG the example of absolutely immune conduct, for which even motivations don't apply? The answer could either dicuss how he could blatantly demand this of the AG, and fire AGs until one agreed, or do the same to the DOD.

@bharring: yeah, it's related, but it was accepted that presidents could do that even before this SCOTUS decision. I thought the Q was mainly what this decision brings to the table. But of course, some people commenting above haven't even heard of pardons to political allies, so... I guess someone could write a more extensive primer on POTUS powers.

Yeah, one of the problems with the fallout is to even understand what the actual changes were, one first needs to understand a lot of different legal and governmental details.

@bharring it's never been a crime for the president to fire the AG.  The immunity protects the president from criminal prosecution, but that doesn't have any effect on acts that aren't crimes because such acts cannot form the basis of a criminal prosecution.

If the military obeys an order to forcibly end the impeachment process, which is clear violation of their oaths taken to the Constitution, the justice branch is equally powerless, and the SCOTUS decision is wholly and irrevocably mooted in that kind of scenario.

@phoog a crime that requires motive, such as attempted murder, might involve demanding AGs murder a political opponent, and firing people when they say no. The "act" of attempting to murder his opponent would be a crime. The act of communicating with and terminating an AG would be absolutely immune. But because he's absolutely immune, even video of him doing so is inadmissible. Worse, even, is prosecutors can't consider his motive, as it's an absolutely immune act. So he can't be convicted.

@bharring firing an AG for refusing to murder someone is not attempted murder.  It may be a crime under some sort of corruption statute, either one covering government officials or RICO.

I named the wrong law in regards to conspiring or commissioning a murder. It's hard to argue demanding someone murder somebody, then punishing them when they do not, is some form of crime. But it's also Article II conduct when it's the President talking to the AG.

@bharring The President can indeed fire the AG - this is within their Constitutional powers - but if they fire the AG to prevent themselves from being charged with murder (which is probably not going to be very helpful anyway, since murder is normally charged at the state level, with no involvement from the US AG,) Congress can still impeach the President,. at which point the former President would no longer be able to fire AGs because former Presidents have no legal powers.

Think about how many people alive today who would be long dead if the president could “kill at will”.
The Supreme Court ruled that a president has the same immunity always given to

every state judge
every Federal judge
every district attorney
every US Attorney
every state’s attorney
every US Congressman

And we have already accepted this.  In 2011, President Obama ordered a drone strike that killed a 16-year-old US citizen named Abdulrahman al-Awlaki.  The administration claimed that the boy was not a target, but there is significant reason to doubt this. Few, if any Americans, believe that Barack Obama can be criminally prosecuted for this death.
I am not convinced of the argument that such absolute immunity — for anyone — is necessary for the government to function, but I must admit it’s a strong argument, and extending it to the president is not unreasonable on its face.

A lot of people are misunderstanding the significance of these ruling. It's less that it grants the American president immunity while in office — there were already some cases establishing this for civil matters, and there was a Justice Department policy that made it the case for criminal matters (and obviously, what Justice Department is going to allow a federal prosecution of the president that appointed it?) It's that it produces a lifetime immunity for such acts, even when the person is no longer president.

@Obie2.0 Immunity for a particular act would be largely toothless if it had an expiration date, or did you mean something else?

@IllusiveBrian - And yet, such immunity did not exist in US case law until the case in question was decided.

@Obie2.0, there was no reason until now for there to be any case law about such immunity. I am troubled by the SC's ruling in this case, but the absence of relevant case law is not at all a concern to me.

@Obie2.0 — why would that be significant?  Most landmark decision were novel — and in this one, there are only 30 people in history to whom it could have applied (presidents who survived their term). Plus, if you look at earlier criminal-presidents like Clinton and Nixon, their successors were clearly dodging the Constitutional issue.

@MichaelLorton - It's significant because previously, there existed the possibility that a court might have held a former president criminally liable for official conduct during office that violated applicable laws, and now it is quite unlikely to do so. I would think the significance is obvious.

@Obie2.0 — courts do not act sua sponte in criminal cases. The courts have not ruled because the Department of Justice has not brought any cases.  Because they didn’t want to provoke a constitutional crisis.

@Obie2.0 judges and so on also have lifetime immunity for official acts, as this answer points out.  Of course, there's no way that ordering an assassination could be an official act of a judge.

@IllusiveBrian What do you mean by toothless? It means that if the President is engaging in a series of acts, they can't be charged and effectively stopped by a court until they've have completed everything and left office. It means that there's no longer urgency, and presidents have been pretty generous with pardons to their predecessors (Ford, George H.W. Bush). And people in their 80s often evade prosecution by natural death. There's a big difference between "can charge during presidency" and "can charge after presidency".

@prosfilaes Because the purpose of the immunity generally is to remove personal consequences from some action that could be bad for the individual but is in line with public policy.  In this case the purpose is to allow the President to make decisions without being concerned about getting thrown in prison later by an opposing party.  If the immunity expires on leaving office then he may have to consider whether any decision he makes can be held against him criminally later.

Actually immunity only while the President is still President would be almost entirely pointless since no one would have the practical capacity to arrest the President during his term, other than a coup at which point law becomes irrelevant anyway.

@IllusiveBrian — no state government could arrest the president.  The DoJ technically has the authority, but long-standing policy is that it does not.  It would be kind of like firing your boss.

@IllusiveBrian Sounds like you're saying that the immunity is toothless because it exists. Yes, people would like unbounded immunity, but the purpose of not giving immunity is discourage a President from taking actions that could be good for the President but is not in line with public policy.

Sure, a president can kill someone, if they have means and opportunity to do so.
But, there are still laws. If a president violates the law, and wants to claim immunity, they and their attorneys would have to be prepared to convince a judge or jury that this is appropriate.
And there would be a prosecutor whose job it is to argue the opposite, beyond a reasonable doubt.
If a president decided one day, for example, that they wanted to walk down Fifth Avenue and kill someone, and they followed through on this, it's hard to imagine what the defense to this could be.

If he has immunity from those laws they don't mean anything.

The question text clarifies that it is about whether the President would have immunity from prosecution in the event they order a government subordinate to kill someone, and in particular, about the implications of the SC's recent decision about presidential immunity for official acts.  This answer doesn't engage any of the main thrusts of that.

Afaik the verdict says that the president can kill only in connection to his official duties. Thus, he can kill at will, for example, people in Iraq. If he just walks on the street and kills random people, that is not official duty, so he would be legally responsible.

@JoeW But that is still an "if". The Supreme Court ruled that a president has immunity under some circumstances and not others. If, for example, a prosecutor were to argue that what the president did does not fall under the scope of their official duties, and a court agrees, then there would be no immunity in that case

@GraySheep I would argue that a president has no more authority to kill anyone in Iraq then they do in the U.S. Killing someone anywhere could only be considered an official duty if there is something about that person or what they did, that could make it a legitimate assassination.

@user3753318 Yes, "killing in Iraq" means that he orders the military to kill bad guys by predator drones, as enemy combatants and terrorists. At least, that is the USA view. A lesser popular view is that he murders the political opponents among with their family, as punishment.

@user3753318 And how long ago was it that we would have thought that a president trying to overthrow the results of an election they lost would be an outlandish situation that never would happen.

@JoeW: Must've been before 2000, when a former vice-president exactly did "try to overthrow the results of an election they lost ".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_v._Gore  Of course, not all challenges to an election are equal (but Trump is in trouble for trying to hash it out through government processes, which qualitatively is what Gore also did).

@BenVoigt Are you really trying to compare a challenge using the court system to a sitting president calling officials to find them more votes or not to certify the votes? Or attempting to submit their own electoral college votes in an order to get different votes counted then what the sate submitted or get those state votes thrown out? Or calling for their supporters to storm the capital building during the vote process? There is a big difference between filing a case in the court system and following the ruling and trying to use any means possible to change the results.

@JoeW: "Asking officials to find more votes" is a pretty good description of Gore's approach in 2000 also.  Bush is the one who sued in court, and did so to STOP that from happening.  I make no claims about everything Trump is in trouble for, only that the thing Gore did and Trump also did, Trump is facing criminal prosecution for.  Separately from any/all other complaints and prosecution against Trump.

@BenVoigt George Bush followed the legally accepted practice of taking the issue to the courts for a decision as happens in many elections across the country on a regular basis. The courts weigh the all of the evidence in order to make a decision. Donald Trump on other hand just called government officials and ordered them to find more votes while ignoring the well established path to contest an election.

@BenVoigt George W Bush and Al Gore both followed the legally accepted practice of bringing their arguments to court. As opposed to Donald Trump, who instead did what JoeW pointed out in his comment above, which was to call election officials and ask them to "find" more votes. That's a big difference. I contend that what Trump did would not be considered by a reasonable judge or jury to be within his "official duties" -- thus, no immunity. This was the crux of my answer above
